# Hazelcast 3.4: how to avoid deserialization from near cache and get original item

Tags: hazelcast

Starting from version 3.X Hazelcast returns copy of the original object that is stored in a distributed map with near cache enabled, as opposed to version 2.5 where original object was returned.

This behavior allowed local modifications of entries stored in the map and GET operations was fast.

Now, with version 3.X it stores binary object in near cache, and it causes deserialization on every GET, which significantly impacts performance.
Is it possible to configure Hazelcast 3.4.2 Map's Near Cache to return reference to original object, and not a copy of the original entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `<near-cache>` section, if you set

- `<in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>`
- AND
- `<cache-local-entries>true</cache-local-entries>`

you should get the same instance returned.

This works for both client and member.

Comment: According to their doc, in this case entity will be deserialized and serialized again - additional performance cost

Comment: @Dmitry I've tested it, and it works. Where in the docs do you see that?

Comment: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/map-inmemoryformat.html In addition, when debugging Hazelcast code, it can be seen that inside NearCache there is ConcurrentMap that stores CacheRecord's where value is stored as BINARY.

Comment: @Dmitry, that describes the behavior of `map`, not `near-cache`. Make sure those two settings above is inside the `<near-cache>` section, not directly in the `<map>` section.

Comment: Oh, you mean to configure near-cache in-memory representation. It worked! However, in the example in near cache documentation this config param is omitted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is a way to get original item. 
To avoid deserialization you could try and set

```
<in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
```

in `<near-cache>` configuration. This way hazelcast will store data in `<near-cache>` in object form and deserialization would not be needed. But I guess this will work only if you configured `<near-cahce>` on the client side, because if `<near-cache>` is on the node you will still need serialization to pass object from node to client.

Comment: Be careful sharing a mutable object :)